# How to scrape specific data from scrape with simple html dom parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I am trying to scrape the price data from a product on an amazon webpage, but I get more than just the price data in the variable, I get other elements included such as `<span>` etc. The code...

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html1 = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.co.uk/New-Apple-iPod-touch-Generation/dp/B0040GIZTI/ref=br_lf_m_1000333483_1_1_img?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&pf_rd_p=229345967&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_t=1401&pf_rd_i=1000333483&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=1ZW9HJW2KN2C2MTRJH60');

$price_data1 = $html1->find('b[class=priceLarge]',0);
```

The variable then also contains data such as `<b class="priceLarge">£163.00</b>`

Is there a way to trim the unwanted data out ? I just need £163.00.

I am unsure if I do it during the find, or perhaps when i echo out the variable, then do I specify what I want ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Change your XPath to select the `text()` child of the `<b>` element, rather than selecting the element itself.

```
$price_data1 = $html1->find('b[class=priceLarge]/text()',0);
```

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
$result=$price_data1->innertext;
```

you will definitely get the desires output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try online API like [Synthetics Web](http://www.syntheticsweb.com/). You can extract data with minimum coding effort.

```
$url = urlencode('http://www.amazon.co.uk/New-Apple-iPod-touch-Generation/dp/B0040GIZTI/ref=br_lf_m_1000333483_1_1_img?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&pf_rd_p=229345967&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_t=1401&pf_rd_i=1000333483&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=1ZW9HJW2KN2C2MTRJH60');
$wid = '160';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.syntheticsweb.com/resources/www.json?wid=$wid&url=$url"));

echo $data->price;
```

Comment: All your answers so far seem to recommend Synthetics Web. Are you in any way affiliated? If so, you will have to clearly state your affiliation within your answers, as stated in the FAQ.

Answer (score -1):

```
<b class="priceLarge">£163.00</b>
```

Simply use the following:

```
$p = "/b class=\"priceLarge\">(.*)<\/b>/";
preg_match($p, $html, $match)
```